# How can I calculate the confusion matrix after executing Yolov7's detect.py?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, confusion-matrix, yolov7

I am currently encountering a problem, the results of yolov7's test.py and detect.py identifying the same test set are not the same.

How can I make detect.py generate a confusion matrix like test.py when it is executed?
I want to see the confusion matrix of detect.py, is this possible?

I have modified the code of yolov7 to generate the confusion matrix, so that the confusion matrix shows the real number instead of the proportion.
I thought that when detect.py did not recognize the **"B"** in the license plate image, the confusion matrix generated using test.py would at least have **"1"** in the **"FN column"** of **"B"**, but apparently it doesn't.

Please see attached pictures by the link - i can't post the image in here.

**This is test.py confusion matrix:**

[This is test.py confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TodSR.png)

**This is the test set image result of detect.py recognition:**

[This is the test set image result of detect.py recognition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1pv5.jpg)

**This is the test set label txt result of detect.py recognition:**

[This is the test set label txt result of detect.py recognition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKb8z.png)

**This is the test set True label txt:**

[This is the test set True label txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL9Te.png)

Here is the code where I modified yolov7\utils\metrics.py so that it displays real quantities instead of ratios.

Orignal version

```
def plot(self, save_dir='', names=()):
    try:
        import seaborn as sn

        array = self.matrix / (self.matrix.sum(0).reshape(1, self.nc + 1) + 1E-6)  # normalize
        array[array < 0.005] = np.nan  # don't annotate (would appear as 0.00)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9), tight_layout=True)
```

My version

I just comment out the `/ (self.matrix.sum(0).reshape(1, self.nc + 1) + 1E-6)`.

```
def plot(self, save_dir='', names=()):
    try:
        import seaborn as sn

        array = self.matrix #/ (self.matrix.sum(0).reshape(1, self.nc + 1) + 1E-6)  # normalize
        
        array[array < 0.005] = np.nan  # don't annotate (would appear as 0.00)
        
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9), tight_layout=True)
```